# Can relative pronoun omitted in this sentence? A post office is a place [where] you can buy stamps

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

Does this sentence need a relative pronoun (**where**) or not and it is a correct sentence in this form?

> A post office is a place you can buy stamps.

Comment: No, words like ***where, which, that,...*** can (always?) be omitted in such contexts, leaving what I suppose is a "reduced relative clause".But you can't discard it in, say, *The Post Office **where** you buy stamps is closed*.

Comment: No: it's fine as written. We can also have a _wh_ relative, as in _A post office is a place **where** you can buy stamps_.  It's a matter of personal choice.

Comment: You don't *buy stamps post office*, but **at** a post office, or **from** a post office. It would help to say "A post office is a place you can buy stamps from," ending with a preposition, or "where you can buy stamps," or "... a place to buy stamps."

Comment: @YosefBaskin - it's perfectly fine for colloquial British [if nothing else].

Comment: @YosefBaskin When the antecedent is a very general noun such as "place", it's OK to omit the terminal preposition as well as the relative word: "A post office is a place (where) you can buy stamps". But in cases with a less general noun as antecedent the relative word is normally required: "There is a high-street shop nearby where you can buy stamps".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In American English, a post office is **a place (where) you can buy stamps**. You can omit **where** and it will still be idiomatic.

You can also say

> The post office *I normally buy stamps at* was closed.
>
> The boots *I usually go hiking in* were in my cousin's car.

but not:

> *The post office I normally buy stamps was closed.

P.S. Consider the following noun phrases which have a relative clause:

> a place that | which sells stamps
>
> a place where stamps are sold
>
> a place where I buy stamps

Which of the above allows the omission of **that|which** or **where**?

> *a place sells stamps
>
> a place stamps are sold
>
> a place I buy stamps

If **place** is the *subject* of the verb in the clause, via its  proxy, then the proxy  cannot be omitted (in standard English, though the omission is permissible in some dialects).

Now consider:

> The post office where I normally buy stamps...

The relative clause needs to refer to the noun it specifies, so you cannot omit **where** unless you refer to the noun in another manner, as the (understood) object of a preposition or as the understood direct object:

> The post office I normally buy stamps **at**
>
> The post office I normally buy stamps **from**
>
> The post office I go **to**
>
> *The post office I go <sup>no, because **go** is intransitive, taking no object</sup>
>
> The post office I like

Comment: Ok, but can you explain *why* we don't need aa *where* here?

Comment: Ok, thanks. So are you saying that I can leave out *where* with ***place***, but not with ***post office***? And if so, why?

Comment: I will have to answer that after Sunday dinner ;-p  It's almost 6PM here.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that **where** cannot be omitted with "post office".

Comment: So which case is the exceptional one?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.  Which case? of omitting where with "place"?  Do you mean something like  **A place I go** , where an understood "there"  serves as the anaphoric reference back to "place"?  That same thing cannot be done with something more particular than "place" :  *A beach I go,  *A church I go, *A bookstore I go...

Comment: What's this pub they were talking about? --Oh, it's nothing special, it's just **somewhere they go after work**.

Comment: When the antecedent is a very general noun such as "place", it's OK to omit the relative word: "A post office is a place (where) you can buy stamps". But in cases with a less general noun as antecedent the relative word is normally required. For example, in "There is a high-street shop nearby where you can buy stamps", "there" is hardly omissible. That's the difference.

Comment: @BillJ:  On the general noun, it's a question of how general the noun feels. This would be OK in my AmE dialect: *Go down to 5th and South.  There's **a tiny shop** you can buy used books for two bucks.*